# When does the Stagewise algorithm stop

Tags: multiple-regression, optimization, gradient-descent

Does the Stagewise algorith stop when the gradient reaches 0?
What if the algorithm never reaches the gradient=0, is there any valid criteria to be used to stop it?

Comment: This is dependent on the implementation. All well-implemented iterative algorithms have an upper limit of allowed iterations; when it is reached the algorithm returns a relevant warning or (in some cases) error.

Comment: @usεr11852 do you know what the limit of allowed iterations for stagewise is? I cannot find anything about how the algorithm should stop. I know just that is should stop when the gradient reaches 0, since it reached a global minimum. But what if it gets stuck in a local minimum, what is the number of iterations to stop it ?

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for the Stagewise algorithm you refer at?

Comment: @usεr11852 http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/papers/stagewise.pdf  page nr. 1

Comment: Page 27. 100 iterations per solution. (You may want this link to your original post)